# jQuery slider - last to first transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created this slider (didn't want to use plugins):

```
function slider(sel, intr, i) {
  var _slider = this;
  this.ind = i;
  this.selector = sel;
  this.slide = [];
  this.slide_active = 0;
  this.amount;
  this.selector.children().each(function (i) {
    _slider.slide[i] = $(this);
    $(this).hide();
  })
  this.run();
}
slider.prototype.run = function () {
  var _s = this;
  this.slide[this.slide_active].show();
  setTimeout(function () {
    _s.slide[_s.slide_active].hide()
    _s.slide_active++;
    _s.run();
  }, interval);
}
var slides = [];
var interval = 1000
$('.slider').each(function (i) {
  slides[i] = new slider($(this), interval, i);
})
```

The problem I have is that I don´t know how to get it after the last slide(image), it goes back to the first slide again. Right now, it just .hide and .show till the end and if there is no image it just doesn´t start again.

Can someone help me out with **a code suggestion** to make it take the .length of the slider(the number of images on it) and if it is the last slide(image), then goes back to the first slide(image)... like a cycle.

**Edit:** Slider markup

```
    <div class="small_box top_right slider">
        <img class="fittobox" src="img/home10.jpg" alt="home10" width="854" height="592">
        <img class="fittobox" src="img/home3.jpg" alt="home3" width="435" height="392">
        <img class="fittobox" src="img/home4.jpg" alt="home4" width="435" height="392">
    </div>
```

Comment: Unless I overlooked something: `_s.slide_active++; _s.slide_active = _s.slide_active % this.slide.length;`

Comment: but I already have _s.slide_active++; in the timeout, why repeat it?

Comment: As per my understanding you have different slides overlap each other. You are hiding slides in a sequence in a time duration to show slide below it. In case of last slide after some time you have to make appear first slide instead hide and when you transaction(first slide appear fully) make all slide appear below it and repeat same sequence

Comment: @fxg that was just for context

Comment: Have you tried running a conditional `if` statement at each `run()` call that determines whether it is the last slide, and then proceed accordingly?

Comment: Can you please share the code(markup) of `.slider` class?

Comment: of course, I put it in the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Created a fixed version for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/vbRLU/).

The easiest way to do this is to run a simple maths operation where you currently have

```
_s.slide_active++;
```

Instead, I get `_s.slide_active`, add `1`, then run that through modulus (`%`) to the total length — which gives the remainder:

```
_s.slide_active = (_s.slide_active + 1) % _s.slide.length;
```

Comment: To better illustrate the effect that it's correctly looping (I have some "duplicate image issues" over here), [this might be a better example based on your answer](http://jsfiddle.net/gmP6b/).

Comment: @MarcoK good point — specified different themes for the images of identical width/height.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you very much! I will give the bounty as soon as the system lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFLG2/8/)** link, this will help you create the slider in a cyclic way.If the slider reaches the last image it will start again from the first image.

```
var index = $selector.index();   
if (index == (length - 1)) {   
    $('img').first().removeClass('invisible').addClass('visible');  
}
```

I hope this will help you more. All the best.

Comment: thanks, but this seems to work with your slider... not with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get to 0 after length-1.
One simple way to do that is to work modulo length:

```
_s.slide_active++;
_s.slide_active %= length;
```

Comment: I put this code but the first image keeps "jumping" to it, no change to the second slide... thanks

Answer (score 0):

not tested but hope helpful :

```
function slider(sel, intr , i){
   ...
   this.count = this.selector.children().length;
   this.run();
}

slider.prototype.run = function(){
    var _s = this;
    this.slide[this.slide_active].show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        _s.slide[_s.slide_active].hide()
        if(_s.slide_active == this.count)
             _s.slide_active = 0;  
        else
             _s.slide_active++;
        _s.run();
    }, interval);
}
```

Comment: it still stops at the last image